# Generic Expose Contained Class possible?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

Lets say I have a bunch of classes of type Base that look like this:

```
public class MyClass1 : Base
{
    private MySubClass1 subClass1;
    public override Base.MySubClass subClass
    {
        get
        {
            return this.subClass1;
        }
        set
        {
            base.MySubClass = this.subClass1;
        }
    }
     public class MySubClass1 : Base.MySubClass
     {
         public string Hello1() {return "hello1";}    
     }
}

public abstract class Base
{
     public virtual MySubClass subClass {get;set;}
     public abstract class MySubClass
     {
         public string Hello() {return "hello";}
     }
}
```

**What I'm wondering is, if it's possible to generically only expose `MySubClass1` through some sort of generic method in a fluent API sort of fashion.**

I was thinking something like:

```
public Base.MySubClass SubFunctions<T>() where T : Base, new()
{
   var x = new T();
   return x.subClass;
}
```

But if i call this, it'll obviously only return the functions inside `Base.MySubClass` rather than the sub class of `T` i would pass into it:

e.g. `cls.SubFunctions<MyClass1>().Hello()` << Will only expose `Base.MySubClass`, not `MyClass1.MySubClass1`

Is there any way to do achieve this without passing `MyClass1.MySubClass` as `T`?

Comment: What does "only expose MySubClass1 through some sort of generic method" mean?

Comment: What i mean is, if i do: `cls.SubFunctions<MyClass1>()...` i would like it to expose `Hello1()`, not just `Hello()`

Comment: First of all, that's not a subclass.  Subclass has a very specific meaning in object oriented programming, and that's when you inherit from a base class, you subclass it.  MyClass1 is a subclass of Base in your case.  What you call a "subclass" is actually a "contained class".  You will find that people will be confused if you use terms that already have specific meanings in ways that are different from their meaning, and you won't get good answers.

Comment: Fair enough. I renamed the title

Comment: Short answer I would say is NO.  You're returning Base.MySubClass anything is going to have to case that result.
It's hard to tell what you're actually trying to design.  If all you want to do is have a standard way of instantiating objects I'd suggest looking at an injection framework like NInject.

Comment: You talk about FLUENT API, maybe you should read this... en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface.  I think the key part of this article for you would be...  "defined through the return value of a called method".  So your method to be "fluent" would have to look something like public T SubFunctions<T>()

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered this?

```
public abstract class Base
{
     public virtual MySubClass subClass {get;set;}
     public abstract class MySubClass
     {
         public string Hello() {return "hello";}
     }

     public abstract MySubClass CreateSubClass();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var hello = new MyClass1().subClass.Hello1();
}

public class MyClass1 : Base<MyClass1.MySubClass1>
{
    public override MySubClass1 subClass{get;set;}

    public class MySubClass1 : Base<MySubClass1>.MySubClass
    {
        public string Hello1() {return "hello1";}    
    }
}

public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>.MySubClass, new()
{
    public Base() {subClass = new T();}
    public virtual T subClass {get;set;}
    public abstract class MySubClass
    {
        public string Hello() {return "hello";}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that makes the method you're trying to create a little more complicated:

```
public TSub SubFunctions<TBase, TSub>() 
    where TBase : Base<TSub>, new()
    where TSub : Base<TSub>.MySubClass, new()
{
    var x = new TBase();
    return x.subClass;
}
```

Usage:

```
var hello = SubFunctions<MyClass1, MyClass1.MySubClass1>().Hello1();
```

You'll note that the nested nature of your "sub-class" classes has no bearing here. They could just as easily be located outside of your other classes.

Comment: I ended up with something similar to what you have suggested, but what i meant in my question was that i did not want to pass in MyClass1.MySubClass1 into the generic method, but go directly to it's functions. e.g. `SubFunctions<MyClass1>().Hello1();`. Which i now think is not possible.

Comment: @malik: No, it's not. But it's possible that there's another solution to the problem you're trying to solve. Usually when I find myself wanting to do something complicated with generics and inheritance, I realize that I'm overcomplicating matters.

Answer (score 0):

> But if i call this, it'll obviously only return the functions inside Base.MySubClass rather than the sub class of T i would pass into it:

You would generally do this through an Interface.
If what you want is to pass around any generic object that implements a special set of features and you only want access to those features then that is exactly what Interfaces are for. Regardles of the underlying type you have defined a specific collection of features that are available

1. First step is to change Base.MySubClass to implement an interface of the functionality that you want to expose

   ```
   public interface INotBaseClassFunctions
   {
       string SaySomethingElse();
   }
   ```
2. Now Implement that interface in MySubClass1

   ```
   public class MySubClass1 : Base.MySubClass, INotBaseClassFunctions
   {
       public override string SaySomethingElse() { return "Something Else :)"; }
   }
   ```
3. For the next bit I think what you want is a sort of factory/provider model.

   > What I'm wondering is, if it's possible to generically only expose MySubClass1 through some sort of generic method in a fluent API sort of fashion

   Your asking "How can I write a generic method that if I specify a type it will give me an object that will only expose my 'Higher level functions' and not the rest of the functionality of that type"?

   > ### This is a good primer for different design patterns: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx
   >
   > Also try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx for the MSDN take on factory patterns, a good read!

   This simple change will likely do the job:

   ```
   public INotBaseClassFunctionsProvider : Interface
   {
       INotBaseClassFunctions GetSubclass();
   }
   ```

   > NOTE: It's up to you how you define that way the underlying type is provided, we generally only use properties in a class if the subclass object is persisted in the provider object, for factories and other interfaces I like to use methods to expose the subclass object because I don't have control over the actual implementation or whether the object will be persisted or not.
   >
   > > When you use methods the caller *must* infer that getting the object is a process in itself that may take time or throw errors.

   ```
   public INotBaseClassFunctions SubFunctions<T>() where T : INotBaseClassFunctionsProvider, new()
   {
      var provider = new T();
      return provider.GetSubClass(); 
   }
   ```
4. So putting this all together, make MyClass1 implement the provider interface:

   > I left your other code in there, but suspect you'll quickly remove the abstract relationship altogether now.
   >
   > > After all, you were asking all along how to abstract functionality without including any of the base class implementation... interfaces are good for *asbstracting* common functionality across unrelated classes
   > >
   > > > that doesn't stop you from using them in types that are related ;)

   ```
   public class MyClass1 : Base, INotBaseClassFunctionsProvider 
   {
       // base class implementation, note that this is not a good
       // coding practise, having a modifier that does not alter the output of the accessor
       // will likely cause headaches for someon down the track, make sure you 
       // document the reason why you have done this, if you ever do it.
       // Using interfaces we can remove the need to implement this base functionality altogether
       private MySubClass1 subClass1 = new MySubClass1();
       public override Base.MySubClass subClass
       {
           get
           {
               return this.subClass1;
           }
           set
           {
               base.MySubClass = this.subClass1;
           }
       }

       // INotBaseClassFunctionsProvider implementation
       public INotBaseClassFunctions GetSubclass()
       {
           return this.subClass1;
       }

       public class MySubClass1 : Base.MySubClass, INotBaseClassFunctions
       {
           public override string SaySomethingElse() { return "Something Else :)"; }
       }
   }

   public abstract class Base
   {
       public virtual MySubClass subClass { get; set; }
       public abstract class MySubClass
       {
           public string Hello() {return "hello";}
       }
   }
   ```

The end result is that when you call SubFunctions();
the object you get back is of type INotBaseClassFunctions, so in this example there is no *strongly typed* access to Hello()

I hope that is helpful in some way and that I haven't misinterpreted your requirements too much :)

Comment: And what's in INotBaseClassFunctions?  Hello1?